# How can I get data from mysql database with json encode (Symfony 4)?

Tags: php, json, symfony, doctrine, server-side

Right now I am getting data from the database via Doctrine:

```
$articles = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Article::class)->findAll();
return $this->render('homepage.html.twig', array('articles' => $articles));
```

This is working fine. But what I need is to get the data via json encode, because I want to use server-side processing datatables. So I try to use the Serializer

```
  $encoders = array(new XmlEncoder(), new JsonEncoder());
  $normalizers = array(new ObjectNormalizer());

  $serializer = new Serializer($normalizers, $encoders);
  $articles = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Article::class)->findAll();
  $jsonContent = $serializer->serialize($articles, 'json');

  return $this->render('homepage.html.twig', $jsonContent);
```

But I get the error message:

> Argument 2 passed to
>   Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController::render()
>   must be of the type array, string given, called in
>   /Users/work/project/src/Controller/ArticleController.php on line 46
>   Uncaught PHP Exception
>   Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: "Argument 2
>   passed to
>   Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController::render()
>   must be of the type array, string given, called in
>   /Users/work/project/src/Controller/ArticleController.php on line 46"
>   at
>   /Users/work/project/vendor/symfony/framework-bundle/Controller/ControllerTrait.php
>   line 219

Comment: You could do it the easy way and to `return $this->render('homepage.twig.html', [$jsonContent]);`. That's also how this bundle does it: https://omines.github.io/datatables-bundle/

Comment: @Loek Wooow, this is what I was looking for for a long time...

Comment: @Loek Did you ever installed this bundle? I tried to install it but get an error message: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51303702/how-can-i-configure-a-non-existent-service-in-symfony-4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So make second argument of `render` an array:

```
return $this->render('homepage.html.twig', ['json_content' => $jsonContent]);
```

In a template:

```
{{ json_content }}
```

Though I don't know why you use a template, as there's a `json()` method which returns single json:

```
return $this->json($articles); // without using serializer
```

Comment: you can also use the twig function to json_encode things: `{{ articles|json_encode }}`