# How can I configure a non-existent service in Symfony 4?

Tags: php, symfony, service, bundles

I installed this bundle and followed the tutorial step by step:

https://omines.github.io/datatables-bundle/#introduction

My Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Omines\DataTablesBundle\Adapter\ArrayAdapter;
use Omines\DataTablesBundle\Column\TextColumn;
use Omines\DataTablesBundle\Controller\DataTablesTrait;


class DataTableController extends Controller
{

  /**
  * @Route("/")
  */

  use DataTablesTrait;

  public function showAction(Request $request)
  {
    $table = $this->createDataTable()
    ->add('firstName', TextColumn::class)
    ->add('lastName', TextColumn::class)
    ->createAdapter(ArrayAdapter::class, [
      ['firstName' => 'Donald', 'lastName' => 'Trump'],
      ['firstName' => 'Barack', 'lastName' => 'Obama'],
    ])
    ->handleRequest($request);

    if ($table->isCallback()) {
      return $table->getResponse();
    }

    $this->render('list.html.twig', ['datatable' => $table]);
  }
}
```

But I get the error message:

> You have requested a non-existent service
>   "Omines\DataTablesBundle\DataTableFactory".

I suppose that there is something missing in the services.yaml file. But in the tutorial they do not say something about it. So maybe it is another reason.

Comment: The documentation does explicitly contain the phrase *"After installation, if not using Flex, you should register the bundle to your kernel"*. This is basic Symfony knowledge and our docs do assume that to be present when developing applications with it using external bundles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That service appears to be defined in the services.xml, itself pulled in by the bundle configuration, and that happens when the bundle is registered in the AppKernel class.

```
class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    public function registerBundles()
    {
        $bundles = array(
            new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
            // ....

            new \Omines\DataTablesBundle\DataTablesBundle(),

            // ... other bundle registration
        );

        if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), array('dev', 'test'))) {
            // ... 
        }

        return $bundles;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you, where do I find the AppKernel class?

Comment: If you are going to be using something, you will have to go and learn the basics of how to use it first.

Comment: I think AppKernel.php is from the old version of Symfony https://symfony.com/doc/3.3/bundles.html The new version does not have AppKernel.php https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles.html

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following line to the return in config/bundles.php. AppKernel doesn't exist in version 4.

```
return [
    ... all other bundles
    Omines\DataTablesBundle\DataTablesBundle::class => ['all' => true]
];
```